# Why does the last estimator of the Sklearn only get fit and not transformed?

Tags: scikit-learn

Here is the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) for the pipeline constructor from Sklearn website:

> Sequentially apply a list of transforms and a final estimator. Intermediate steps of the pipeline must be ‘transforms’, that is, they must implement fit and transform methods. *The final estimator only needs to implement fit.* The transformers in the pipeline can be cached using memory argument.

I do not understand why isn't the final estimator being used to transform the input?

Comment: "Here is the example ... " where is the example ? Is this question complete ?

Comment: Sorry about that...I will correct it soon!

Comment: @steffen - I've made the correction. I removed the example as this is a theoretical question and not a coding one. Thank you for pointing this out :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final estimator (i.e. final step in the pipeline) **may be** a transformer, but it does not have to be. It could be a classifier instead. Hence the final step may *transform*, but it can *predict*.

For the case of the last step being a transformer, pipelines support a method called *fit_transform*. See the referenced documentation and linked User Guide for more details.